# Golang: unmarshal nested struct with private field

Tags: go

Hello I would like to pass a json to a struct in case I have entity and value objects and in all my value objects I have the methods: UnmarshalText, MarshalJSON
to transform my struct to json works normal, but I'm not able to imagine how to transform from json to struct
In a scenario where I get data from my person entity database I need to transform this data into a struct person to return

```
for rows.Next() {
    var id, firstName, lastName, email, password string
    var createdAt, updatedAt time.Time

    err = rows.Scan(&id, &firstName, &lastName, &email, &password,
        &createdAt, updatedAt)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to build item: %v\n", err)
        return persons, err
    }

}
```

so far i have my fields in primitive data and i would need to transform it into my struct person which is:

```
type Person struct {
    Id       string    `json:"id"`
    Name     Name      `json:"name"`
    Email    Email     `json:"email"`
    Password Password  `json:"-"`
    Created  time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    Updated  time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`
}
```

as I said before all my object values ​​like email, name, password
have private fields and I have unmarshal and marshal methods in them
i would like to know if there is any way to pass a json to my struct Person

**Email Struct:**

```
type Email struct {
    value string
}
```

Password Struct :

```
type Password struct {
    value string
}
```

**Name Struct:**

```
type Name struct {
    firstName string
    lastName  string
}
```

in all my "structs of a value object I have two methods":

```
//name
func (n *Name) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(struct {
        FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
        LastName  string `json:"lastName"`
    }{
        FirstName: n.FirstName(),
        LastName:  n.LastName(),
    })
}

func (n *Name) UnmarshalText(f []byte, l []byte) error {
    var err error
    *n, err = NewName(string(f), string(l))
    return err
}
//password
func (n *Password) UnmarshalText(d []byte) error {
    var err error
    *n, err = NewPassword(string(d))
    return err
}

func (e *Password) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(e.Value())
}
//email
func (e *Email) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(e.Value())
}

func (n *Email) UnmarshalText(d []byte) error {
    var err error
    *n, err = NewEmail(string(d))
    return err
}
```

Comment: postgres, my table person has this fields : id, first_name, last_name, email, password, created_at, updated_at